# Is it possible to define a task timeout on AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I just need to know if there is any way to define a timeout while running tasks on AWS ECS Dockers

**EDIT:**
I have tried setting the **ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT** variable, but this is the timeout to kill the docker, I want a timeout to kill the task

Comment: What if you have a CloudWatch Rule that triggers a Lambda that kills the task?

Comment: Is there no other way? We need to scale this to kill every task

Comment: The lambda could use the ecs list-tasks api to list all tasks then you could kill them all. I am not sure there is another way

Answer (score 8):

not at the moment, there's a feature request for that on:

https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/291

ecs tasks are supposed to run your process/code without a time limit (compared to lambda where you have a 15 minutes timeout)

my first suggestion would be to run your docker in a lambda:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/

if you can't or don't want to change... what you can do is configure a timeout function inside your application an call a `stop-task` cli action

you will need the cluster name or arn and task name or arn in your cli command

to have access to that from within your application, first enable [container metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html)

now you can [query the agent endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-introspection.html):

```
curl http://localhost:51678/v1/metadata
curl http://localhost:51678/v1/tasks
```

make sure to check the metadata url for ec2 or fargate instances:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html

general actions:

- [1] Enable Metadata: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html
- [2] Query Container Metadata for Cluster and Task Name or ARN
- [3] Write a timeout function within your application and call `aws ecs stop-task --cluster <value> --task <value>` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/stop-task.html

**Pros:**

- extremely cheap, you don't need extra resources from aws

**Const:**

- you need to write/create the code for the timeout and integrate metadata etc

Answer (score 1):

Another suggested solution described here [1] is to use step-function that reads task's tags and stop the container if timeout tag specified. See [1] for more details

[1] - https://it20.info/2023/03/configuring-a-timeout-for-amazon-ecs-tasks/